# Explaining a program in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a simple prolog program which is supposed to write all of the factors of a selected number. However I am starting to think that I can never learn prolog. I just don't get how the program works. The code is below.

```
deli(X):-
    deli(X,1).
deli(X,X):-
    write(X),nl.
deli(X,N):-
    Z is X mod N,
    Z==0,
    write(N),nl,
    N1 is N+1,
    deli(X,N1).
deli(X,N):-
    N1 is N+1,
    deli(X,N1).
```

Answer (score 0):

`deli/2` counts up a counter `N` (initially set to 1 on the call from `deli/1`) and prints its value if it is equal to the given number `X` (first clause) or if it cleanly divides `X` (second clause). In the latter case, it increments `N` and continues to search for the next factor.

It then backtracks and goes off into an infinite loop.